# IOS - Como editar escala de uma view por Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, xcode

Tenho uma view chamada viewV e gostaria de alterar seu **Width** e **Height** mostrado na imagem abaixo via código em Swift.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode usar a opção **Aspect Ratio**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode realizar isso com esse código a baixo :

```
let x = CGFloat(0)
let y = CGFloat(0)
let height = CGFloat(100)
let width = CGFloat(100)

viewV.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, height, width)
```

Sua viewV normal

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sua viewV Modificada com o código
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Seria interessante você usar `NSLayoutConstraint`s para isso. Ficaria via código (mais ou menos) assim:

```
// Constraints
let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: viewV, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewV.superview!, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let leadConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: viewV, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewV.superview!, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: viewV, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0.0, constant: 667)
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: viewV, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0.0, constant: 267)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([topConstraint, leadConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
```